# How to know which row in fstab need to be changed to relatime/noatime?

Tags: iostat

If I run iostat I saw this:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.36    0.78    9.66   21.46    0.00   52.74
Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda             180.34       494.08      5741.44   28772164  334347968
sdc               0.01         0.08         0.00       4492          8
sdb               0.01         0.09         0.01       5412        736
sdd               0.32         6.64        12.68     386732     738656
dm-0             93.32       110.10       731.99    6411692   42626904
dm-1              0.01         0.05         0.00       2680          0
dm-2            647.62       383.52      5009.47   22333866  291722528
```

Looks like dm-0, dm-2 is the culprit. Most likely it's read turning into write because iotop shows:

```
10583 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10582 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10705 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10733 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10766 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 8894 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10974 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 9059 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 9156 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 1011 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 7272 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
11409 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
11445 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
11447 be/4 mortgage    0.00 B/s   60.34 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [php]
 4298 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
11454 be/4 mortgage    0.00 B/s  218.73 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [php]
 5698 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 1440 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10030 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10061 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10093 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10094 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 6073 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
10231 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    7.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 2048 be/4 named       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % named -u named
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    4 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    6 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
```

My fstab is this:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root    /   ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0    1   1
UUID=1450c2bf-d431-4621-9e8e-b0be57fd79b6 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home    /home   ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0    1   2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
/dev/sdb1               /home2                  auto    auto,defaults         0 0
/dev/sdc1               /home3                  auto    auto,defaults         0 0
/dev/sdd1               /home4                  auto    auto,defaults         0 0
```

The problem is which one is dm-0, dm1, and dm-2? I suppose I'll just change defaults to defaults,relatime, but which rows?

if I do ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/

I got

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Dec 26 05:03 dm-name-VolGroup-lv_home -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Dec 26 05:03 dm-name-VolGroup-lv_root -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Dec 26 05:03 dm-name-VolGroup-lv_swap -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Dec 26 05:03 dm-uuid-LVM-U0gpPI6UFcotbgHEwlPqKQOw6tPYQ1pjamluUcU2YJ5xYPp2re51sVkE0LyxI2qy -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Dec 26 05:03 dm-uuid-LVM-U0gpPI6UFcotbgHEwlPqKQOw6tPYQ1pjjec2s02YQq8Dpw65ynU42qYnSWuTlPc2 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Dec 26 05:03 dm-uuid-LVM-U0gpPI6UFcotbgHEwlPqKQOw6tPYQ1pjVufBZh0L0hG8uFJ9cWxsBkEJQ0OvNX1H -> ../../dm-1
```

There are 2 entries for /dm-0 to dm-2. I wonder why. I suppose I got what I need for now. As I suspect, the swap is not the issue. Root and home is the issue which is kind of strange given that all accounts at /home has already been moved somewhere else.

Comment: `sudo /sbin/fdisk -l`, `df -h`, `sudo dmsetup ls`?

Comment: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` should work aswell

Comment: please turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` should do the trick